# Calculating probability in questionnaire answers

Tags: probability

I'm designing a piece of research and want to quote the probability of two unique responses matching.
10 questions, for each answerer is required to select a,b or c. Therefore, if selecting randomly there's a 33.33% chance of ansering the same. What would be the overall probability of answering all 10 questions the same?

is it 33.33 X 33.33 x 33.33 X 33.33 x33.33 X 33.33 x33.33 X 33.33 x33.33 X 33.33? How would one express this as a percentage chance?

Answer (score 3):

The probability of all ten answers being the same is $(1/3)^9 \approx 0.00005$ or 0.005%.

You can think of this as:

Pr[first answer is A, B or C] * Pr[second is same as first] * ... * Pr[tenth is same as first]

$= 1 \cdot (1/3) \cdot \ldots \cdot (1/3) = (1/3)^9$

Note: this is very different from the probability that, of the 10 answers, at least two are the same. In your first sentence you mention wanting to express "the probability of two unique responses matching," but later you ask for the probability of giving the same answer to all ten questions. Which event do you care about?

Also, a note that might seem nitpicky: when you say "if selecting randomly, there's a .33 chance of answering the same," you're making an assumption that people are selecting answers (not just randomly, but) uniformly at random. You could imagine that people choose answers A, B and C with, respectively, 0.98, 0.01 and 0.01 probability (why not), and that would completely change the answer to your question.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Adrian. I think you're on the right track here, but I wonder if there's also something else. The question asks about the probability of answering every question the same & there are $3$ possible answers. What you have seems like the probability of every answer being $a$.

Comment: @gung I think the probability of all 10 answers being A is (1/3)^10, while the probability of all 10 anwers being the same is (1/3)^9

Comment: oh dear, I feared this would be more complicated than I envisioned. 0.005% probability should be fine for the purposes of my work. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, @Adrian, I think I mis-read your answer. +1